# The evaluation of $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{1/x^2} = e^{1/3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Wolfram Alpha says:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^{1/x^2} = e^{1/3}$$

What are the steps leading to this result?

Only with the Hospital rule, I have as a result infinity.